# How to get max date from a date column and create temporary dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create temporary dataframe based on max date but this is now working. Can you please help me how to do this?

example:

DF:

```
table_name     count     load_dt
case           100       2020-04-19
case           110       2020-04-19
case           120       2020-04-19
case           130       2020-04-19

print(DF['load_dt'].max())
2020-04-19
```

I want temporary dataframe like given below:

```
TEMP_DF:

Table_name      count     load_dt
case            130       2020-04-19
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['load_dt'].idxmax()]` ?

Comment: @anky can you please write sample code for this?

Comment: I didnt get you :-) , `print(df.loc[df['load_dt'].idxmax()])` should give you want you want